# Unable to connect WebApp to Virtual Machine using VNET

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have a web app built on .Net 4.6. The application utilises elasticsearch and redis which are hosted in an Azure VM. I am trying to connect Azure VM(ElasticSearch+Redis) to Azure WebApp(.Net WebApp) using internal network. i.e, WebApp and VM should interact with each other on LAN and not the internet. I am not able to understand Azure VNET use case scenario from its description in docs.

Does Azure VNET enable the above-mentioned scenario? If yes, How? If No, Please suggest the best way to archive this.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, could you please let me know why are you using a VM for Redis and Elastic Search?

With regards to your questions, you can definitely do that. Please read Getting Started at the below link to understand -

[Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/)